# How to generate and store a uuid type 0x04 in mongodb using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, uuid

I am trying to store in mongodb a uuid type 4 but when I call the InsertOne function this is storing my uuid as type 0 (generic) and not type 4.
I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
type Document struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    FcrID      string    `bson:"fcrId" json:"fcrId"`
    ContextKey string    `bson:"contextKey" json:"contextKey"`
    PrivateKey string    `bson:"privateKey" json:"privateKey"`
    PublicKey  string    `bson:"publicKey" json:"publicKey"`
}

for _, message := range messages {
        body := message.Body
        fmt.Println("new messaged received, writing keys to database")

        id := uuid.New()

        var jsonDocument common.DocumentKey

        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonDocument)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        d, bsonErr := bson.Marshal(common.Document{
            ID:         id,
            FcrID:      jsonDocument.FcrID,
            ContextKey: jsonDocument.ContextKey,
            PrivateKey: jsonDocument.PrivateKey,
            PublicKey:  jsonDocument.PublicKey,
        })
        if bsonErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(bsonErr)
            return
        }

        err = databaseOperations.InsertData(ctx, mclient, "management", "keys", d)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        err = receiver.CompleteMessage(context.TODO(), message, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

but the id is being stored as BinData 0 but I would like to have BinData 4.

I know uuid will return a [16]byte but I don't understand why mongo is understanding it as a generic data to be stored and not as a proper uuid type 0x04.

how can I make mongodb store my uuid as type 4 and not 0?

Thank you

Comment: You should just pass a value of `Document` to `Collection.InsertOne()`. Doesn't that work?

Comment: this is what I am basically doing

result, err := coll.InsertOne(ctx, document) and this document is the populated structured result from bson.Marshall but when I check the id in the database this is
"_id" : BinData(0, data),
but should be BinData(4, data).

Comment: I'm suggesting to simply pass `Document`, not the output of `bson.Marshal()`.

Comment: the same Bindata(0, data), just tried.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the actual impact to you of MongoDB stating the wrong bindata subtype? It looks like the MongoDB driver may not support storing the UUID subtype: ["There is currently no UUID type provided by the Go driver or Go BSON library that has any special marshaling/unmarshaling behavior."](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/using-build-in-uuid-function-from-the-driver-in-golang-mongodb/206207/2)

Comment: @Adrian the impact will be in my queries, I would like to have my own user defined uuid to be able to handle my queries, as a generic type I won't be able to query by my own uuid.
as this generic type is generated on mongo side.
My uuid is basically being ignored and if I store it as string it works but the performance is really bad compared with binary.

Answer (score 2):

it worked, very simple

```
type Document struct {
ID         primitive.Binary `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
FcrID      string           `bson:"fcrId" json:"fcrId"`
ContextKey string           `bson:"contextKey" json:"contextKey"`
PrivateKey string           `bson:"privateKey" json:"privateKey"`
PublicKey  string           `bson:"publicKey" json:"publicKey"`
}

    id := uuid.New()

    binId := primitive.Binary{
        Subtype: 0x04,
        Data:    id[:],
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store a **UUID** as type 0x04 in MongoDB using Golang, you need to ensure that the **UUID** is properly serialized as a binary subtype `0x04` before being inserted into the database.
here, i can give you an example code snippet that shows how to generate a **UUID** type `0x04` and store it in MongoDB:

***Sample Code***

```
import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
)

// Defined my document struct
type Document struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    FcrID      string    `bson:"fcrId" json:"fcrId"`
    ContextKey string    `bson:"contextKey" json:"contextKey"`
    PrivateKey string    `bson:"privateKey" json:"privateKey"`
    PublicKey  string    `bson:"publicKey" json:"publicKey"`
}

func main() {

    // then, Create a new UUID of type 0x04
    id := uuid.New()
    
        // Serialize the UUID as a binary subtype 0x04
    idBytes := id.Bytes()
    idBytes[6] = (idBytes[6] & 0x0f) | 0x40 // Set the version byte to 4
    idBytes[8] = (idBytes[8] & 0x3f) | 0x80 // Set the variant byte to the RFC 4122 variant
    idBinary := bson.Binary{
        Subtype: 0x04,
        Data:    idBytes,
    }
    fmt.Println("  idBinary : ", idBinary)

    // now, Create a new document instance
    doc := &Document{
        ID:         uuid.Nil, // this, ID will be automatically generated by MongoDB
        FcrID:      "my-fcr-id",
        ContextKey: "my-context-key",
        PrivateKey: "my-private-key",
        PublicKey:  "my-public-key",
    }
    
    fmt.Println("  doc : ", doc)
    // Serialize the document to BSON
    bsonDoc, err := bson.Marshal(doc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" ~ marshal : ~ err : ", err)
        
    }

    // Set the ID field to the binary UUID value
    bsonDoc[4] = 0x04 // Set the BSON type for the ID field to binary
    bsonDoc = append(bsonDoc[:5], idBinary.Bytes()...)
    bsonDoc = append(bsonDoc, 0x00) // Add a null terminator to the BSON document

    // Insert the document into the MongoDB collection using insertOne() command
    collection := mclient.Database("MyDB").Collection("MyCollection")
    _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, bsonDoc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" ~ insertOne(): ~ err : ", err)
        
    }
}
```

you first generate a new **UUID** using the `uuid.New()` function.  then, you serialize the **UUID** as a binary subtype `0x04` by setting the version byte to 4 and the variant byte to the *RFC 4122 variant*.
you create a new document instance and serialize it to **BSON** using the `bson.Marshal()` function. Finally, you set the ID field to the binary **UUID** value and insert the document into the MongoDB collection using the `collection.InsertOne()` function.